# Use jquery to modify table row when table rows input changes

Tags: jquery

Below is an example of a table row that I'm generating dynamically. I'm trying to use jQuery to modify the extendedprice td via the input above. IE change the quantity. I had example working partially, but my selector was selecting ALL the extendedprice td rows. I think i was incorrectly using the next selector. Unfortunately in a fit of rage last week i deleted the portion that was working instead of commenting it out.

```
<th>
<input class="form-control partQuantity partQtyInput" data-outrightp="$12.57" type="text" placeholder="1">
</th>
<td>000-126042</td>
<td>Nipple Filter</td>
<td>$12.57</td>
<td class="extendedPrice">$12.57</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here it is. First your `input`'s `data` attribute should not contain special characters. Assuming its the price of the item. So i remove it. The implement a basic mathematical computation assuming its (price * qty)

I use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the current `row` and [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the nearest class. So that it will only affect `td` with class of `extendedPrice` in the 
 same row.

```js
$(document).on("change",".partQtyInput",function(){
  var amount = $(this).data("outrightp");
  var total = ($(this).val() * amount).toFixed(2);
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.extendedPrice').html('$'+total);
  console.log(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<input class="form-control partQuantity partQtyInput" data-outrightp="59.2" type="text" placeholder="1">
</td>
<td>000-95959</td>
<td>Desktop</td>
<td>$59.2</td>
<td class="extendedPrice">$59.2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input class="form-control partQuantity partQtyInput" data-outrightp="12.57" type="text" placeholder="1">
</td>
<td>000-126042</td>
<td>Nipple Filter</td>
<td>$12.57</td>
<td class="extendedPrice">$12.57</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This solution worked PERFECT. Literally all I had to do to my code was copy and paste your code. I added .replace to strip the "$" from the numbers and added a function call that calculates and then displays my totals. In addition thank you for explaining your jQuery selectors!